# PHP cast object to appropriate datatype based on its value

Tags: php, xml, object, casting, type-conversion

I have some objects which come from an XML file. I am trying to convert the XML file to SQL data structure. So far, I managed to retrieve the tables and columns and now I need to find out data types for each column. 
`gettype()` didn't help since it always returns `object`.
Casting is not efficient, I tried to cast to every data type to see if it suits one but, for example, if I cast `5hi` to integer, the result would be `5`.
Here is a part on XML file:

```
<device>
    <manufacturer>SIEMENS</manufacturer>
    <model>SOMATOM Definition</model>
    <serial>60301</serial>
    <version>syngo CT 2010A</version>
</device>
```

So, as an example, `manufacturer` is `string` and `serial` is `integer`.
How can I cast an object to appropriate datatype based on its value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[is_numeric](https://www.php.net/is_numeric) Will provide you with the capacity to check if a value is numeric

If you're looking to ensure integers, loop over each character and use [ctype_digit](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ctype-digit.php)

You may also wish to use [regular expressions](https://www.php.net/preg_match) to recognise more complex structures.

Example:

```
if(is_numeric($value)) {
    $value = doubleval($value); //cast to double
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I first cast the object to string and then checked with other functions.